Show the joint continuity of the solution $x$ in the variables $(t,\lambda)$.
I am learning Picard's theorem on Existence and Uniqueness to understand integral curves and flow in a better way.I have got stuck with an exercise which is as follows:

Exercise:
Suppose $\Lambda\subset \mathbb R^N$ is open and $X:U\times \Lambda\to \mathbb R^n$  where $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ open.Assume further that $X$ is Lipschitz in the variable $x$ i.e. there exists a constant $L$ such that $\|X(x,\lambda)-X(y,\lambda)\|\leq L\|x-y\|$ for all $x,y\in U$ and $\lambda\in \Lambda$.
Then there exists a unique solution $x(t,\lambda)$ to the initial value problem $X(x(t,\lambda))=x'(t,\lambda)$ with initial condition $x(0,\lambda)=x_0$ adn the solution is jointly continuous on $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]\times \Lambda$ for some suitably small $\epsilon>0$.

Can someone help me to come up with a proof of this result?I have been thinking about this exercise but yet not able to do this.Maybe I am missing something.
Suggestions from my MSE peers is highly appreciated.

I am a bit confused, is L independent from the choice of \lambda? Is x_0 independent from the choice. of \lambda? what is the meaning here of the variable t? It seems to me that the role of \lambda is to being a punch of parameters and for each fixed parameter \lambda you have a solution in t, so x(t,\lambda). However, $X$ is not defined in U x \Lambda x R, so I am missing something. Is the function X not depending by t? By the way, if you prove this result, it should be true also if you assume X depending from t. Moreover, when you write X(x(t,\lambda)), do you mean X(x(t,\lambda), \lambda)?

@FedericoFallucca Please write in proper LaTeX Notation otherwise it is not readable.
